# Counting number of articles within a category using CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple `cakephp` app with table `articles` that has a `cat_id` column to reference a `id` column of categories in a `cats` table.

What I would like to do is display all categories names, each followed with a count of the number of articles belonging to that category.

I know there is a `find('count')` function in `cakephp`, but that only working on one table/field. How do I link the two tables to get a list of category names and count of articles for each category for my view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be better to do this in the afterFind callback on the model but can be done in the controller aswell.

```
$cats - $this->Cat->find('all',array('recursive'=>-1));
foreach($cats as $key=>$cat){
  $cats[$key]['ArticleCount'] = $this->Cat->Article->find('count',array(
     'conditions'=>array('Article.cat_id'=>$cat['Cat']['id']))
  );
}
```

or see if this works

```
$cats = $this->Cat->find('all',array('contain'=>array(
          'Article'=>array('fields'=>array('COUNT(*) AS ArticleCount')
        )));
```

obviously you will need to add the containable behavior on the category model.

Answer (score 4):

COme on! Use counterCache!
In table "cats" create field article_count. In Model write

```
/app/models/cat.php
class Cat extends AppModel
{
   var $name = 'Cat';
   var $belongsTo = array('Article'=>array('counterCache'=>true));
}
```

That's all! every time you add/remove from articles, it writes to cats table count of articles.
don't forget to include article_count into fields list

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the countercache feature: http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count

Answer (score 2):

You also might consider checking out [counterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count) to cache the count within a column value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this worked:

```
        $cats = $this->Article->Cat->find('all',array('recursive'=>-1));
    foreach($cats as $key=>$cat){
      $cats[$key]['ArticleCount'] = $this->Article->find('count',array(
         'conditions'=>array('Article.cat_id'=>$cat['Cat']['id']))
      );
    }
```

Comment: That probably works, but I think there is a better way. you should use the Set::combine function instead of the foreach. Something like this I think is more efficient:

$category_count = $this->Article->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Category.name', 'COUNT(Article.id) AS num_articles'),
    'group' => 'Category.id',
    'conditions' => $conditions
));
$category_count = Set::combine($category_count, '{n}.Category.name', '{n}.0.num_articles');

This assumes your model relations are set up correctly.

Comment: This works, but to dhofstet's point you're duplicating code that already exists in the model in the form of CounterCache.